# Difference in directory size between Baobab and System Monitor

Tags: ubuntu, diskspace

I tried running a process (specifically [Fuzzotron](https://github.com/denandz/fuzzotron)) on my Ubuntu 18.04.2, and noticed that I'm slowly losing disk space. When I killed the process, I got the disappearing space back.

When I tried running the process again, I wanted to see where the space is going to (maybe to some ever increasing log file that is deleted when the process terminates), so I used Baobab. However, after a few minutes of running, I noticed that Baobab is reporting `/` having a certain size (which doesn't change), while System Monitor does see the increasing used space.

[image: Baobab on the left, System Monitor on the right]

As seen in the screenshot, Baobab (left) claims only 34.5GB are being used, while System Monitor (right) claims 39.9GB are being used.

Does Baobab not detect certain files?

If that's the case, what should I do in order to find this mysterious disk space drainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find ${1} -type f | xargs stat --format '%Y :%y %n' 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2-
```

to find out recently created files in your filesystem.
This will shed some light on the actual behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, found a bunch of files that were created in `/dev/shm`